# Calculating the orthogonal projection for polynomial functions

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials

The task is:

> Let ${E := {ax^3+bx^2+cx+d : a, b, c, d ∈ R}}$ be the vector space of
> all real polynomials of degree at most 3 and let ${F}$ be the
> subvector space of all real polynomials of degree at most 2. On ${E}$
> we consider that for p, q ∈ ${E}$ by.
>
> $${\langle p|q \rangle := \int_{0}^{1}{}p(x)q(x)dx}$$
>
> given scalar product. Calculate the orthogonal projection ${P_F(x^3)}$
> and the distance of the monomial ${x^3}$ zu ${F}$.

I am honestly a bit confused and overwhelmed with this. Since I have no clue and am looking for some sort of help to understand this properly. I spent some time googling and using ChatGPT to get around it eventually. The way I found and I tried is:

Finding a basis of F, which could be:
$${ax^2+bx+c \Rightarrow x^2+x+1}$$
Then I set:
$${P_F(x^3) = ax^2+bx+c}$$
Then I calculated the scalar product. With ${p(x) = x^3}$ and tried finding ${\langle p|P_F(x^3) \rangle}$. This is equal to ${\frac{1}{6}}a + {\frac{1}{5}}b + {\frac{1}{4}}c = 1$. I thought = 1 makes sense since when they both are equal it would be 1. And now I would want to calculate a, b and c. But it feels like this makes no sense and I'd need more equations to do so. I would appreciate a hint or a method to solve this! Thank you.

Comment: Well, how am I doing this. Can I simply say a,b = 0 and then solve this for c? And do this as well with b,c = 0 and a,c = =?

Comment: You can get 3 equations by requiring that $x^3-ax^2-bx-c$ is orthogonal to $1,x,x^2.$ Then $ax^2+bx+c$ is the projection.

Comment: So just to clarify what to do: ${p(x) = x^3-ax^2-bx-c}$
I just calculate the scalar product from p(x) and 1, p(x) and x and finally, from ${x^2}$ and p(x)?

Comment: Yes. These scalar product should be equal $0.$ Hence you get three equations.

Comment: Alright, I did this now and come to following equation:
${x^3-1.5x^2-0.6x+0.05}$. But is this now for ${x^3}$? And how do I calculate the distance between these. Sorry for that stupid question o.O

Comment: The projection is equal $1.5x^2+0.6x-0.05$ and the distance is equal $\left (\int_0^1(x^3-1.5x^2-0.6x+0.05)^2dx\right)^{1/2}$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc 
To clarify, the projection is now the vector orthogonal on F. And I am just trying to find the distance? Or is this a point and ${x^3-1.5x^2+0.6x-0.05}$ is the vector then?
My a = 1.5, b = -0.6 and c = 0.05. To correct my previous results.

Comment: The vector connects $x^3$ and the projection $1.5x^2-0.6x+0.05. $ The difference $x^3-1.5x^2+0.6x-0.05$ is treated as the vector connecting these points. Concerning your deleted comment $\|p\|=\langle p,p\rangle^{1/2}.$ That's why there is a square inside the integral.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Okay thanks a lot, I think I understand most of it now. Not too complicated once I figure it out. But could you maybe explain why we say ${x^3-ax^2-bx-c}$ and say exactly this one needs to be orthogonal. What if say ${ (ax^2+bx + c)}$ and then do the same as I did before?This is just for me to understand exactly what we did here :) you helped me a lot!

Comment: Alright, I think I understood it now! We just simply form the vector from F to ${x^3}$! Thus, we need to do the math with this vector. The vector from the previous vector would not point to ${x^3}$ and won't help at all.